# How Do I Show A Live Video Feed On A C# Form?

Tags: c#, video-streaming

I have a C# Windows Form Application and a live video feed.  I need a way to display the live video feed on one of the forms.  Does anyone have any ideas?

We're using a robot and getting the video feed off a camera attached to it, so we will not be using the internet at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [AForge.Net](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/). [Here](http://haryoktav.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/webcam-in-c-aforgenet/) is a tutorial for pulling webcam data and displaying in a form.